# C#, WPF. Changing or binding label content from static method

Tags: c#, wpf, udp

I have static method which receives udp packets asynchronously.
I need to change label content, but i don't know how to do that correctly without using MVVM.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {    
          public int MyMethod()
          {
                    //My method which counts some errors in received packets.
                    //Return error_count;
          }

         public void UdpData(IAsyncResult result)
         {                   
                     UdpClient socket = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
                     IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.10"), 20000);
                     byte[] message = socket.EndReceive(result, ref source);

          socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(UdpData), socket);
      }

      public MainWindow()
      {
                 InitializeComponent();

                 socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(UdpData), socket);
      } 
}
```

I need to receive packet(done), use my method for received bytes(done) and show errors count with my label.

Comment: Where is the code of Label. What's it's name. And what string it should be updated with?

Comment: Is the data xml?  Then parse data with an xml class.

Comment: `<Label x:Name="Error_count"></Label>`

Comment: And this is my method which returns errors count. 
Need to bind "err" to my label.

ushort BER(byte[] Src, byte[] Org, ushort len)
        {
            byte XR = 0;
            ushort err = 0;
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < len; cnt++)
            {
                XR = Src[cnt] ^= Org[cnt];
                for (int lcn = 0; lcn < 8; lcn++)
                {
                    if (((XR >> lcn) & 1) == 1) err++;
                }
            }
            return err;
        }

Comment: Add a handler for when the socket receive has ended then inside that call your static method to parse the result which you then use to update the label as: `Error_count.Content = $"Error Count { MyMethod() }";`

Comment: Thanks! Can you show me how to add handler?

Comment: Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a Name to a window's element in WPF, you can access to this element from the codes.

you can simply access to it:

```
 Name.Content = $"number of errors : {Counter}";
```

Comment: Not in that way